# Spring Autowiring stopped working on GAE

Tags: spring, hibernate, google-app-engine, autowired

I'm sure my app worked right until yesterday, when I got this error:

> Failed startup of context 
>   com.google.apphosting.utils.jetty.RuntimeAppEngineWebAppContext@1079ff{/,/
>   base/data/home/apps/s~trewnewmedia/1.357617962256387950} 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
>   creating bean with name 'scadenziarioController': Injection of 
>   autowired dependencies failed;  nested exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not 
>   autowire method: public void 
>   it.trew.prove.web.controllers.ScadenziarioController.setScadenzaService(it.
>   trew.prove.services.ScadenzaService);  nested exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
>   creating bean with name 'scadenzaService': Injection of autowired 
>   dependencies failed;  nested exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not 
>   autowire method: public void 
>   it.trew.prove.services.ScadenzaService.setSocietaService(it.trew.prove.serv
>   ices.SocietaService);  nested exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
>   creating bean with name 'societaService': Injection of autowired 
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not 
>   autowire method: public void 
>   it.trew.prove.services.SocietaService.setSocietaDao(it.trew.prove.model.dao
>   .Dao);  nested exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
>   creating bean with name 'dao': Injection of resource dependencies 
>   failed;  nested exception is 
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
>   creating bean with name 'mySessionFactory': Post-processing of the 
>   FactoryBean's object failed;  nested exception is 
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Unable to get members for class 
>   org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl

I am using Hibernate with Google Cloud SQL, and it always worked.

On my local machine, with local MySQL, it still works!

I don't think it's a Cloud SQL issue, because removing some autowiring (a test) it still connects and so on. Here's my xml:

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>it.trew.prove.model.beans.Scadenza</value>
                <value>it.trew.prove.model.beans.Fornitore</value>
                <value>it.trew.prove.model.beans.Societa</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/setup.sql</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

A piece of my DAO:

```
@Component
public class Dao {

    @Resource(name = "mySessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
...
```

And my service:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SocietaService {

    private Dao societaDao;

    @Autowired
    public void setSocietaDao(Dao societaDao) {
        this.societaDao = societaDao;
    }
...
```

I can't find what's different between GAE and my local (mvn gae:run).
And why last week that worked perfectly.

**Please GAE team, support me! I'm going crazy on this issue**

(I'll probably start a bounty, it's too much urgent)

**EDIT** my pom.xml hibernate part:

```
<!-- Hibernate framework -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <!--hibernate-dependencies is a pom, not needed for hibernate-core-->
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: The core problem is: `Unable to get members for class org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl` have you update your Hibernate module or something?

Comment: What is the last modification you did before this error? You must have done something if it was working before.

Comment: no modification! There's something wrong about GAE I think. I deployed to another server and it works. It simply cannot instance my session factory bean. I can't get why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the @Transactional annotation on the @Service class. It uses javax.naming.NamingException in some part I don't know, and that's not a whitelisted class.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that SessionFactoryImpl references a class that google doesn't have on it's whiteliste and it cant' be loaded in that case.

Here's an article about that: http://googlecloudsql.blogspot.de/

Comment: and so? what's the solution for using hibernate??

Comment: Well it seems that you can't just use ANY class as you would in a standalone application. Here's a list of all allowed classes: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html

Comment: If your application is using JPA I would simply use a different JPA Provider. It semms that it's currently simply not possible to use Hibernate out of the box on the Google Cloud. But I have found some article about someone actually have it up and running ... so mabe this helps: http://cloud.dzone.com/articles/spring-hibernate-google

Answer (score 1):

Fabio helped point me in the right direction. I found that declarative transactions using @Transactional do not work in GAE because Spring scans org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl which causes the loading of javax.naming classes which are not on the GAE whitelist. I had the same issue switching to XML based declarations. So I ended up using programmatic transaction management using TransactionTemplate objects and that appears to be working.

EDIT: Added code sample

From my spring configuration I removed `<tx:annotation-driven/>` to disable @Transactional and replaced it with

```
<bean id="defaultTransactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="transactionManager"><ref local="transactionManager"/></property>
</bean>
```

If you're using multiple transaction semantics e.g. PROPAGATION_REQUIRED and PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS, you'll have to create additional beans, one for each scenario e.g.

```
<bean id="supportingTransactionTemplate" class="org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate">
    <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_SUPPORTS"/>
    <property name="transactionManager"><ref local="transactionManager"/></property>
</bean>
```

I left my original service classes with the @Transactional notation. It doesn't matter since `<tx:annotation-driven/>` has been removed and I might switch back some day if the issue is fixed. Instead I sublcassed them to use TransactionTemplate

```
public class GAEUserService extends UserService {

    @Autowired
    private TransactionTemplate defaultTransactionTemplate;

    @Override
    public void update(final User user) {
        defaultTransactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                UserService.super.update(user);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The one downside I found was that I had to convert checked exceptions thrown by my service methods to unchecked exceptions because checked exceptions don't agree with the signature of doInTransactionWithoutResult

Comment: I hope the GAE team will take care of that soon it's really important. Can you please post the code you used? Just for example thank you