# Hibernate SessionFactory bean without Spring

Tags: spring, hibernate, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Due to some GAE limitations, I cannot use the Spring session factory.

```
<bean id="mySessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="myDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>it.trew.prove.model.beans.Scadenza</value>
                <value>it.trew.prove.model.beans.Fornitore</value>
                <value>it.trew.prove.model.beans.Societa</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">create</prop>
                <!-- <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.import_files">/setup.sql</prop> -->
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

See my other question if interested in it: [Spring Autowiring stopped working on GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783773/spring-autowiring-stopped-working-on-gae)

Now I want to create a session factory without org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

How can I configure the pure session factory bean, using only hibernate stuff?

Answer (score -1):

Why are you wanting to use hibernate with GAE? Are you using CloudSQL or the datastore? AppEngine isn't really meant for hibernate type stuff... you're much better off looking at using Objectify or Twig, or if you want an ORM solution, JDO.

Comment: I do use Cloud SQL, obviously. Sorry for not mentioning it.

Comment: This seems to be a comment rather than an answer.