# AppEngine + CloudSQL + Hibernate: @Transactional is forbidden

Tags: spring, hibernate, google-app-engine, transactional, google-cloud-sql

Referring to question [Spring Autowiring stopped working on GAE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9783773/spring-autowiring-stopped-working-on-gae) I ask:

**why doesn't AppEngine allow me to use @Transactional hibernate-jpa annotation?**

AOP (aspectj)  configuration does not work, too.

It uses **javax.naming.NamingException** in some part I don't know, and javax.naming is blacklisted in GAE.

Any of you know a workaround?

I'm currently using "manual" programmatic transactions (via Spring Hibernate PlatformTransactionManager), but it's not very comfortable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are some workaround on our issue tracker:
http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1240

We're aware of this feature request. Please star that issue.